# Convert std::vector<std::string> to const char* const*

Tags: c++, vector, c++17

I'm working with Vulkan, and I'm trying to pass my validation layer as a `vector<string>`. But the field `ppEnabledLayerNames` from [VkInstanceCreateInfo](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0/man/html/VkInstanceCreateInfo.html) only takes `const char* const*`. I don't understand the type and how to convert my vector's data into it.

```
std::vector<std::string> v = {
    "VK_LAYER_LUNARG_standard_validation"
};

const char* const* data = std::accumulate(std::next(v.begin()), v.end(),
                                    v[0],
                                    [](std::string a, std::string b) {
                                        return a + b;
                                    }).c_str();
```

But when I compile, I got this :

```
error: cannot convert ‘const char*’ to ‘const char* const*’ in assignment
                     }).c_str();
```

[Here's a live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/df937ab36fa46e31)

Comment: Using Vulkan from C++17 without [Vulkan-hpp](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Hpp)

Answer (score 3):

With `c_str` you will get `const char*`. A `const char* const*` is an array of `const char*`.

```
  vector<string> vectorOfStrings = {
    "Aa", 
    "Bb", 
    "Cc"
  };

  vector<const char*> vectorOfCStyleStrings(3);

  // convert from string to C style strings
  for (string item : vectorOfStrings)
    vectorOfCStyleStrings.push_back(item.c_str());

  // get vector like a const C style array
  const char* const* arrayOfCStyleStrings = vectorOfCStyleStrings.data();
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do it on a `std::string`:

```
const std::string str = "test";
const char* str_p = str.c_str();

const char* const* ppEnabledExtensionNames = &str_p;
```

Be careful if `c_str()` is part of a temporary string that's getting trashed. You may need to retain a reference to the base string object until you're done with this.

Comment: The vector of string is given to the function by copy. Would there be a way to concat all the data of the vector into a single `const char*` ?

Comment: Isn't that what `accumulate` is doing? You're combining all the strings into a single string.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you're doing in your snippet:

- concatenate all the strings in `v` (or crash if `v` is empty);
- throw away the resulting string;
- try to assign a dangling pointer to `const char` to `const char* const*`.

The last part did not compile, but that's a good thing - dealing with this in a runtime would be a sad expirience.

By the looks of the interface (namely the `ppEnabledLayerNames` parameter) one could guess that you don't want to concatenate the strings in the first place, but instead you want to pass an array of c-strings.

Here is how to get it from `vector<string>`:

```
vector<const char*> layer_names(v.size());
std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), layer_names.begin(), [](const string& s)
             { return s.c_str(); });
const char* const* data = layer_names.data();
```

Notice that it will only be valid until either `layer_names` or `v` is destroyed.

The better way would be to find a C++-friendly interface for Vulkan, I can't help with that though.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution this morning, using `std::accumulate`

```
auto d = std::accumulate(
    std::next(v.begin()), v.end(),
    v[0],
    [](std::string a, std::string b) {
        return a + b;
    }).c_str();

const char* const* data = &d;
```